# Javascript function overloading, pls explain John Resig (Jquery way) article

Tags: javascript

I understand implementing JavaScript overloading based on arguments object, or by explicit checking type of and length of arguments.please explain this article: http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-method-overloading/.

Comment: What part do/don't you understand? It's not really an appropriate question for StackOverflow. I don't mean to be pedantic, but this site is geared around specific technical questions. For grasping an understanding of general topics, it's too broad. Maybe e-mail the author and ask him? **jeresig@gmail.com**

Comment: Explaining which part doesn't make sense will allow us to give you a focused answer rather than explaining every single details. Also, make sure you step through the code using a debugger.

Comment: Closures is the key. Take a look at this: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two concepts in the function below that I think could be the source of your confusion.

- `addMethod` keeps a reference to previously added function as a closure stack using `var old = object[name];`.
- `addMethod` knows how many arguments a function was defined with using `Function.length`(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) and compares that with the closure stack it creates. If it doesn't match, it goes up to the next one(); That's what John Resig is referring to as the overhead this method creates.

The logging created by the code below should help you see what's happening.

```js
// addMethod - By John Resig (MIT Licensed)
function addMethod(object, name, fn) {
  var old = object[name];
  object[name] = function() {
    if (fn.length == arguments.length) {
      console.log('Arguments and parameters count are the same, found the function');
      return fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    if (typeof old == 'function') {
      console.log('Arguments and parameters count are not the same, try the next function in the closure stack');
      return old.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  };
}

function Users() {
  // This will be at the bottom of the stack, every call will have to go through the functions below
  addMethod(this, "find", function() {
    console.log('Called with 0 arguments');
  });
  // This will be at the middle of the task
  addMethod(this, "find", function(name) {
    console.log('Called with one argument');
  });
  // This is the one with the least overhead
  addMethod(this, "find", function(first, last) {
    console.log('Called with two arguments');
  });
}

var users = new Users();
users.find();
users.find('John');
users.find('John', 'Resig');
```

Remember to step through functions when trying to understand them. Right click on the image below and choose "open image in new tab"

[image: Closure stack]

Here's an `addMethods` will a little less overhead and IMHO, nicer syntax and less repetition.

```js
// addMethods - By Juan Methods, inspired by John Resig (MIT Licensed)
function addMethods(object, name /* fn, fn, fn ... */ ) {
  // Key is the parameter count for each passed in function, value is the function itself */
  var functionMap = {};
  for (var i = 2; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    functionMap[arguments[i].length] = arguments[i];
  }

  object[name] = function() {
    functionMap[arguments.length].apply(this, arguments);
  };
}

function Users() {
  // Now every function has constant overhead of a single map lookup, which
  // is less expensive than multiple method calls up the closure stack
  addMethods(this, "find", 
    function() {
      console.log('Called with 0 arguments');
    }, 
    function(name) {
      console.log('Called with one argument');
    },
    function(first, last) {
      console.log('Called with two arguments');
    }
  );
}

var users = new Users();
users.find();
users.find('Jack');
users.find('John', 'Resig');
```